# Segmentation fault in C while using isdigit() and argc

Tags: c, cs50

I am having the following issue: Segmentation fault (core dumped).

I looked around at the other questions on StackOverflow and didn't see the correct answer to my question.  Here is my code :

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf("missing command-line argument\n");
    return 1;
}

for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
    printf("Made it inside");
    if (isdigit(argv[i]) == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
string plain_text = get_string("plaintext: ");
int key = atoi(argv[1]); //function to convert a string to int. 


for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plain_text); i < n; i++)
{
    int c = (int) plain_text[i];
    c += key;
    printf("%c", c);
}
printf("\n");

return 0;

}
```

The error is coming from "if (isdigit(argv[i]) == 0)".

EDIT:

Here is the solution, thanks all!

```
 for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
{
    if (isdigit(argv[1][i]) == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a `string` which is actually a `char *` to `isdigit`. You need to pass the first character of the string instead

```
isdigit(*argv[i][0])
```

Comment: This is what I tried to do initially and for some reason, it didn't work the first time but it's working now I think!

Comment: @logankilpatrick remember this will only check the first character in the string. If you are trying to check if the entire string is made of digits you will have to use a different method :)

Comment: My code does this, loops through each character of the 2nd command line argument:

Comment: You may have added an extra `*` (or `[0]`).

Comment: @Bob__ why would I have to add one of those?

Comment: You got me wrong (or I didn't explain myself well). If you declare `char **argv`, what type is `*argv[i][0]`? A triple dereference is a bit too much.

Comment: @Bob__ its a `char`

Comment: Sorry, [no](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dGxkzERXpXvb2RNX). `argv[i][0]` is a `char`.

Answer (score 3):

isdigit expects an int, you're giving it a string (actually a null terminated group of chars)

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/isdigit.html

While the behavior is listed as "undefined" in this case, I'm not actually sure why you would get a segfault from it.

Comment: Hey Terry, If I already know it's an int, why would I want to use the isdigit function? I thought the point was that it should allow for non-int types to be passed in..

Comment: @logankilpatrick There is a difference between a *digit* and a *number*. A digit is represented by a single character, which is an integer type in C. But a character might or might not represent a digit.

Comment: @logankilpatrick If the argument is not an int but a char, there will be no possible to set `EOF`

Comment: @logankilpatrick I have no idea what the philosophy was behind the function. All I can tell you is what it expects and how it's defined to behave. I think you're trying to see if the entire argument is a number like "12345". If so, there are a bunch of libraries and code snippets you can use. If you need to handle decimals and separators, definitely find a library since it's a lot more complex than it looks.